Why do i get exited with code 0 when i start a localstack container?
Localstack container exited with code 0
I have the following code:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3,iam
      - DEBUG=1
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - backend-network
    # deploy:
    #   resources:
    #     limits:
    #       cpus: '2'
    #       memory: '4G'


when docker-compose up and check the logs, i get
LocalStack supervisor: starting
LocalStack supervisor: localstack process (PID 15) starting
LocalStack supervisor: localstack process (PID 15) returned with exit code 0
LocalStack supervisor: exiting
LocalStack supervisor: starting
LocalStack supervisor: localstack process (PID 14) starting
LocalStack supervisor: localstack process (PID 14) returned with exit code 0
LocalStack supervisor: exiting

i am not sure what is happening. Why is it not working?

I tried to reproduce this issue using your template but was unable to. Please refer to the localstack documentation here, that outlines how to start localstack using docker-compose.
Altenatively, you can use one of the other methods to start it:

localstack CLI
localstack desktop
dockerfile or docker extension
helmchart (if using K8s)

